# undefined method `sender_id=' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

currently I am creating a snapchat like application by using Rails. I get the error:

> undefined method `sender_id=' for nil:NilClass

while I am trying to submit the new message form, I don't really know where I make the mistake. Moreover, I am not sure about the logic of the create action in my messages_controller, basically I just want the sender sends a message to the people in their friendlist by choosing one or more recipients at the same time(of course, the recipients must be in their friendlist, and I have already accomplished this feature). However, because I still haven't figured out how can I pass the the params recipient_id to the form(I am using simple form gem and devise gem by the way), so I hardcoded the recipient_id in my create action. So,all of suggestions/advices are welcome. 
Here are my files:

**messages_controller.rb**:

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @message = Message.new
  end

  def create
    @message.sender_id = current_user
    @message.recipient_id = current_user.friendships.friend_id
    @message = Message.new(message_params)
    if @message.save?
      flash[:success] = 'Message sent successfully'
      redirect_to welcome_profile_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private

    def message_params
      params.require(:message).permit(:body, :sender_id, :recipient_id, :user_id)
    end
end
```

**messages/new.html.erb**:

```
<h1>Create New Message</h1>

<%= simple_form_for @message do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :body %>
  <%#= f.association :user, :as => :hidden, :input_html => { :value => current_user.id }, :include_blank => false %>
  <%= f.button :submit, "Send Message", class: "btn btn-secondary" %>
<% end %>
```

**message.rb**:

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, foreign_key: :recipient_id

  belongs_to :sender, :foreign_key => :sender_id, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :recipient, :foreign_key => :recipient_id, class_name: 'User'

  validates_presence_of :body

end
```

**user.rb**:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  validates :username,
  :presence => true,
  :uniqueness => {
    :case_sensitive => false
  }

  validate :validate_username

  def validate_username
    if User.where(email: username).exists?
      errors.add(:username, :invalid)
    end
  end

  has_many :friendships
  has_many :friends, :through => :friendships
  has_many :inverse_friendships,  :class_name => "Friendship", :foreign_key => "friend_id"
  has_many :inverse_friends, :through => :inverse_friendships, :source => :user

  has_many :messages, dependent: :destroy

end
```

**schema.rb**:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160316170009) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "friendships", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "friend_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "messages", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text     "body"
    t.boolean  "read"
    t.integer  "sender_id"
    t.integer  "recipient_id"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
  end

  add_index "messages", ["user_id"], name: "index_messages_on_user_id", using: :btree

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.inet     "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.inet     "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
    t.string   "username"
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true, using: :btree
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true, using: :btree
  add_index "users", ["username"], name: "index_users_on_username", unique: true, using: :btree

  add_foreign_key "messages", "users"
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error is because you don't have `@message` defined before setting `@message.sender_id` in your `create` action.  Move `@message = Message.new(message_params)` to the top of the `create` action before setting `@message.sender_id` as follows:

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
  ...

  def create
    @message = Message.new(message_params)

    @message.sender_id = current_user
    @message.recipient_id = current_user.friendships.friend_id
    if @message.save?
      flash[:success] = 'Message sent successfully'
      redirect_to welcome_profile_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private

    def message_params
      params.require(:message).permit(:body, :sender_id, :recipient_id, :user_id)
    end
end
```

The second part of the question - `current_user` is available in your controllers, so you don't need a hidden field for that. You can call `@message.sender_id = current_user.id` in  your `create` action as you currently have.  Next, to set `@message.recipient_id`, you could update your `new.html.erb` as follows:

```
# new.html.erb
<h1>Create New Message</h1>

<%= simple_form_for @message do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :body %>

  <%# Updated the following line. You could chose to create a hidden field here, or however you wish to implement this in your view as long as you specify `recipient` as the association or `recipient_id` as the field. %>
  <%= f.association :recipient, :include_blank => false %>

  <%= f.button :submit, "Send Message", class: "btn btn-secondary" %>
<% end %>
```

With the above setup your `create` action could be updated to:

```
 # app/controllers/messages_controller.rb

 def create
    @message = Message.new(message_params)
    @message.sender_id = current_user

    if @message.save?
      flash[:success] = 'Message sent successfully'
      redirect_to welcome_profile_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

Comment: Thank your for your detailed answer. Now I can send the message, but the thing is the dropdown menu in my form doesn't show the name(username column in my user table) of the recipients, instead it show something like this: #<User>:0x007f00d85581f8>. Moreover, it shows all the users in my database. I just want it to show the people who are in the friendlist of the sender. Is something wrong with my logic in the messages_controller?

Comment: Please read on [Associations](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#associations) which should guide you to how you can setup the collection and what to display in the select option with what value.